# How do I get server stacktrace for paster/waitress application on client side

Tags: python, logging, pyramid, paster, waitress

I'm running a python pyramid application and make restful calls to it. It's a wsgi app and uses waitress as the http server. Currently when I make a failing http request, I get messages like:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an unexpected internal server error
```

How would I configure waitress or paster itself to get errors that show the stacktrace, like so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../pyramid/eggs/waitress-0.8.8-py2.7.egg/waitress/channel.py", line 337, in service
    task.service()
  File "/.../pyramid/eggs/waitress-0.8.8-py2.7.egg/waitress/task.py", line 173, in service
    self.execute()
  ...
  File "/.../pyramid/eggs/pyramid-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 469, in _class_requestonly_view
    response = getattr(inst, attr)()
  File "/.../pyramid/dustin/views.py", line 139, in delete
    raise Exception('DELETE op failed; oid %s not found' % deleteItem)
Exception: DELETE op failed; oid 00x not found
```

My paster config is:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:myegg

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.debug_templates = true
pyramid.default_locale_name = es

couchdb.uri = http://couchdb-host:5984/
couchdb.db = myegg

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543

# Begin logging configuration

[loggers]
keys = root

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = [sys.stdout]
level = DEBUG
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s

# End logging configuration
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use an [Exception View](http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pylons/exceptions.html) to catch any exceptions, and return the stacktrace in the response?  I've used something similar to catch all my Pyramid exceptions, log them, but then display back to the user a "friendly" error page renderer.

Comment: Thanks Peter.. I was wondering if there was a way to tell the middleware to pass the stacktrace along.. a quick inspection tells me that it's waitress that "eats" the exception at present.